# Organizing Classes/Modules Collectively in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'd like to use the format:

```
--models
----fooModel.ts
----barModel.ts
----gooModel.ts
----carModel.ts
----...etc
--services
----fooService.ts
----barService.ts
----...etc
--utilities
----fooUtility.ts
----barUtility.ts
----...etc
```

...To store my classes/etc, with one class per file. I'd then like to (ideally) group them up somehow, or reference them collectively, by folder. Either something like:

```
import {Models} from "../models";
```

Or create a new file called "_models.ts" that would look something like this:

```
export module Models {
  //reference fooModel
  //reference barModel
  //continue referencing
};
```

...That I could then reference such as:

```
import {Models} from "../models/_models.ts"
```

Is something like this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Typescript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) on how to wrap modules and combine all their exports using the syntax:

```
export * from "module"
```

I have added an example from the documentation:

```
//AllValidators.ts

export * from "./StringValidator"; // exports interface StringValidator
export * from "./LettersOnlyValidator"; // exports class LettersOnlyValidator
export * from "./ZipCodeValidator";  // exports class ZipCodeValidator
```